# how to add conditions in treeList custom finder in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, treeview, cakephp-3.0

I am using TreeBehavior for generate tree structure using custom finder treeList custom finder

```
$this->Categories->find('treeList',['spacer' => '__']);
```

Now how can i add some conditions like `"isactive" =>true`. I have checked the documentation there are only 3 param. unable to find the condition param

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's less of a "custom" finder, more of a built-in one, given that it ships with the CakePHP core.

That being said, conditions can be added the same way as with any other finder, that is, either via the `conditions` option passed to the second argument of the `find()` method, or via the query builders `where()` method.

Quote from the docs:

> Once you’ve started a query you can use the [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html) interface to
>   build more complex queries, adding additional conditions, limits, or
>   include associations using the fluent interface.
>
> ```php
> // In a controller or table method.
> $query = $articles->find('all')
>     ->where(['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')])
>     ->contain(['Comments', 'Authors'])
>     ->limit(10);
> ```
>
> You can also provide many commonly used options to find(). This can
>   help with testing as there are fewer methods to mock:
>
> ```php
> // In a controller or table method.
> $query = $articles->find('all', [
>     'conditions' => ['Articles.created >' => new DateTime('-10 days')],
>     'contain' => ['Authors', 'Comments'],
>     'limit' => 10
> ]);
> ```

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**